# Receiving Internal Server Error 500 when I call a method in the frontend (Ionic) that works correctly when I test it using postman to the backend

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, ionic-framework, frontend

I created a method (MongoDB) which takes a voucher's price and a user's points. Once this method is called the user's points are deducted by the price of the voucher. I tested the method in the backend using postman and it works fine. It returns the user and the points get deducted correctly.
I connected the method with the front end Ionic, just like any other method, however every time it gets called it returns Error 500: Internal Server Error.

I tried to create another method called getPoints() (which works backend/frontend) which gets the user's points without having to access the user's points in the same method because I thought this might be a problem but the same thing happened, calling updateUserPoints() returned Error 500 once again.

The updateUserPoints method:

```
module.exports.updateUserPoints = async function(req, res, next) {

var priceofvoucher = req.body.price;
var p=req.body.points;
p=p-priceofvoucher;

User.findByIdAndUpdate(
  {_id:req.decodedToken.user._id},
  {
    $set: { "points":  p}
  }
  ,
  { new: true }
).exec(function(err, updatedUser) {
  if (err) {
    return next(err);
  }
  if (!updatedUser) {
    return res
      .status(404)
      .json({ err: null, msg: "User not found.", data: null });
  }

  res.status(200).json({
    err: null,
    msg: "User was updated successfully.",
    data: updatedUser
  });
});
};
```

The service of the method in the frontend:

```
updateUserPoints(p,voucher) {
var headers = new Headers();
headers.append("Authorization", "Bearer " + this.getAuthorizationToken());
headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
return this.http
  .post(environment.apiUrl + "/user/updateUserPoints", p + voucher,
  {
    headers
  })
  .map(res => res.json());
  }
```

The page's html file (vouchers part):

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let voucher of vouchers | async">
    <ion-item>
      {{ voucher.offer }}
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item-options side="end">
      <button ion-button color="danger" (click)="removeVoucher(voucher)">
      <ion-icon name="trash"></ion-icon>
      Delete
    </button>
    </ion-item-options>
    <button (click)="subtraction(voucher)" ion-item>
      <ion-icon name="cart" item-start></ion-icon>
      Buy this Voucher
    </button>
  </ion-item-sliding>
</ion-list>
```

The page's typescript file:

```
subtraction(voucher) {
this.authService.getPoints().subscribe(data => {
this.p = data;
this.showToast(data.msg);
this.updateUserPoints(this.p , voucher.price);
this.loadVouchers();
});
}
```

getPoints() returns "data": 5 for example if the User has 5 points

Comment: you should check your server's error logs....

Comment: I tried printing a print statement in the beginning of the method getPoints() and updateUserPoints()  when I click on the button in the front end which calls subtract which calls both of them, only the print statement in getPoints() gets executed while updateUserPoints() doesn't so I think it might be a problem with the front end right?

Comment: 500: internal server error === server error

Comment: Here is what I get in the backend when I click on subtract:

Comment: POST /api/user/updateUserPoints 200 221.543 ms - 260
OPTIONS /api/user/getCurrentPoints 204 1.093 ms - 0
the points
GET /api/user/getCurrentPoints 304 185.085 ms - -
OPTIONS /api/user/updateUserPoints 204 0.332 ms - 0
POST /api/user/updateUserPoints 500 3.404 ms - 141

Comment: you're likely doing something different on your front end than postman does, and possibly something wrong, but either way a server error should really never be returned as it means there is something unhandled on the server.

Comment: those are access logs, you need error logs

Comment: _body: "{"err":{"expose":true,"statusCode":400,"status":400,"body":"12","type":"entity.parse.failed"},"msg":"500 Internal Server Error","data":null}"
This is the body of the error

Comment: so it's saying that it can't parse whatever you're sending it. and for some reason, your server is choking on that and responding 500.  it should give a 400 with a clear message outlining what happened like: "invalid json in body" or something like that... looking at your front end code, it's now clear that you are definitely sending an invalid post body

Answer (score 2):

issue appears to be here:

```
.post(environment.apiUrl + "/user/updateUserPoints", p + voucher,
```

`p+voucher` doesn't look like it would be a valid json object, you might be after:

```
.post(environment.apiUrl + "/user/updateUserPoints", {points: p, price: voucher},
```

if you want a body with properties points and price corresponding to values of p and voucher respectively, but it's difficult to say for sure without knowing what the actual body is expected to look like.

You should also try to figure out why your server is choking on errors when it can't parse the body of a post request so that it can send you proper error messages instead of 500

Comment: This is the body I am trying to send :
{ "points": 10,
"price": 5}
When I used the new post that you sent it shows me:
"{"err":{"message":"Cast to number failed for value \"NaN\" at path \"points\"","name":"CastError","stringValue":"\"NaN\"","kind":"number","value":null,"path":"points"},"msg":"500 Internal Server Error","data":null}"

Comment: you've gotta add some logging into your front end of what p and voucher are when you feed them in to updateUserPoints... now the message is telling you that points is not a number